# Is Davinci Resolve 16 good for beginers?

Tags: video-editor, davinci-resolve

I have just started video editing. I have little experiences, and I want good free software for video editing.

When I was searching on the internet I came across Davinci Resolve 16. T know it's profession software but is the community for it big enough to get started?

Comment: That's a difficult question to answer. It depends on the person learning, how well they can teach themselves and the search skills they have for finding answers. I suggest you have a go with it, and if you come across any specific questions, don't hesitate to ask them here. It is professional level software, reasonably intuitive, and most of all, if you find out that it's not for you, you haven't lost a Tolar.

Comment: Why is "free" (no money) important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, in Resolve you only have to pay premium for the cloud collaborative features.

Its not beginner software like iMovie or WMM, but rather comparable to Premiere, the cheapest rate for which is 20/month if you have a student email.  Among free software, Resolve is definitely one of the best options out there.

While it is a professional tool, it's very intuitive for basic functions and it has the core features you'll find in other professional editing software.

Edit: Free version includes 4k

Comment: I have tried it yesterday. I like it. Realy.

Comment: The free version of Resolve lets you export up to UHD 4K (3840x2160), inclusive.